# Want to have pictures next to each other in my gallery (Html)

Tags: html, css, position, gallery

Basically I have put a gallery into the website that I am making, and it works well. But. The pictures just scroll down the left side of the screen. I would like half of the pictures to be to the right of the other pictures... Here is a screenshot of my website (With Hi-tech red boxes drawn in paint to show where I would like half of the pictures to go)

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=hx3fbb&s=8#.U2JPKYFdX-k

Here is my code....(html)

```
          <div class="img">
             <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/Ss1.jpg">
   <img src="Gallery/Ss1.jpg" alt="Screenshot1" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Death vs Colossus</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/Ss2.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/Ss2.jpg" alt="Screenshot2" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Death's forge</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/Ss3.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/Ss3.jpg" alt="Screenshot3" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Death vs Horseman</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/Ss4.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/Ss4.jpg" alt="FanArt1" width="500" height="400">
  </a>


  <div class="desc">Horse Jump</div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/fa1.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/fa1.jpg" alt="FanArt1" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Fan Art #1</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/fa2.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/fa2.jpg" alt="FanArt2" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Fan Art #2</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/fa3.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/fa3.jpg" alt="FanArt3" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Fan Art #3</div>
</div>
<div class="img1">
  <a target="_blank" href="Gallery/fa4.jpg">
  <img src="Gallery/fa4.jpg" alt="FanArt4" width="500" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Fan Art #4</div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS code;

```
div.img
  {
  margin:5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
div.img img
  {
  display:inline;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
  }
div.img a:hover img
  {
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
  }
div.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:120px;
  margin:5px;
  }
```

So again, I would basically like the Fan art pictures to appear to the right of the Screenshot pictures. I tried making a new div class for the fan art and changing the float to 'right' but that didn't work.

Thankyou in advance for your time and input :)

Comment: Have you considered a grid layout?

Comment: You do not have to add the "div" before your class selectors in your css. This makes for more work for you and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different methods you could use for this. You could use floats or `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Davidicus/p4Qkh/

Here is a simple float example.

I have a pen where i am using "inline-block" to float elements. Click on the little eye icon in the css panel to see the compiled css.

http://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/vxIra